# Facebook posting on page through application

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've used an application to make posts to my page timeline.

The posts are correctly posted, but they are visible only by the page admin, not other users (ones that liked and ones that didn't liked the page).

The application has all permissions to the page, and to the admin of the page.
The page is set to show all posts to everyone.
Other posts which are posted directly from the page, not through the application can be seen from everyone.

My question is why the posts aren't shown to every users (ones that liked and ones that didn't liked the page)?

Comment: Is your application in sandbox mode?

Comment: Can you please show us the api call you are using? Is this to the stream?

Comment: Yes it was in sandbox mode, now i disable it, that was the problem! Thanks! :)